# How to showing realtime logs from server in jsp textarea?

Tags: ajax, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, struts

Actually i need to show server's real time logs in Jsp textarea in a dynamic way.I have got logs by using ajax callback method but I do not know this is right way or not. Is there any solution to synchronize the server and client for fetching server logs to jsp, please help me.

Comment: From where are you getting logs from server? where logs are stored?

Comment: After generating logs in server side it stores in database and I am fetching these logs using ajax but I do not know this is right way or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are retriving logs from database with finegrane timestamp then the ajax polling will be the best approach. I would recomand cacheing logs after retriving from database if your applications has a large userbase.
Here is a good tutorial for longpolling. you can reduce the wait time.

[Long polling using jquery](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63568/HTTP-Push-from-SQL-Server-Comet-SQL)

Answer (score 0):

Ajax request can get the logs from the server side, it's Poll Mode.
If you want a better performance, You can use a Ajax Push technology pattern known as Comet. 
Here's the project called CometD.

http://cometd.org/

Comment: Yes I have solved by using DWR reverse Ajax. Thank you Andy Fong